# My testbench always shows X as the outputs

Tags: module, verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

I'm not able to identify the bug, but all the code seems logically and syntactically right. The value of `sum` and `carry` in the testbench are always X.
There are two modules, one for an 8bit adder and another for a 16bit adder :

```
module adder_8(in1 , in2 , cin , sum , carry);

input [7:0] in1 , in2;
input cin;
output reg [7:0] sum;
output reg carry;

always @(in1 or in2) begin
    {carry , sum} = in1 + in2 + cin;
end
endmodule

module adder_16(input_a , input_b , c , summation , cout);

input [15:0] input_a , input_b;
input c;
output [15:0] summation;
output cout;

wire t1;

adder_8 inst1 (input_a[7:0] , input_b[7:0] , c , summation[7:0] , t1);
adder_8 inst2 (input_a[15:8] , input_b[15:8] , t1 , summation[15:8] , cout);

endmodule
```

The test bench file is :

```
module testbench;

reg [15:0] a,b;

wire [15:0] sum;
wire carry;

parameter zero = 1'b0;

adder_16 ex(a , b , zero , sum , carry);

initial begin

    $monitor($time," A = %d , B = %d sum = %d carry = %b", a , b , sum , carry);

    #10 a = 16'd 100; b = 16'd 100;

    #10 a = 16'd 50; b = 16'd 20;

    #20 $finish;

end
endmodule
```

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

`cin` is missing from the sensitivity list in `always @(in1 or in2)`. It should be  `always @(in1 or in2 or cin)` to be complement with the 1995 version of the standard. The 2001 version of the standard improved it to `always @*` (or the synonymous `always @(*)` for an automatic sensitivity list.

If you are targeting for SystemVerilog, use `always_comb` (no `@` or signal list). This will add an extra compile time check to make sure a the logic is not assigned in another always block which would make the code non-synthesizer.

Comment: Thank you... the program works fine now. But why does this affect the value of 'sum' in the tesbench ?

Comment: In Verilog, the default behavior of anything plus an unknown is unknown (ex `4'd10 + 1'bx` will return `4'bxxxx`)